# Multiple Label to toggle Checkbox

Tags: css

I'm trying to make this CSS be flexible and use in an HTML table and be able to only change the element in focus without using JavaScript -- but because of the selectors, it is only changing the first element. I'm not the best CSS developer.

I understand that using the `"for="` and repeating the `id`s of the checkboxes we are rendering invalid HTML, but I was wondering if there was a way around it. I tried to give each parent `span` a unique `id` and generate separate classes for them, as well as the labels. but that seemed like it could be an unnecessary amount of work.

Previously I had no use to include these in a table, except now I do.

Is there an easy/flexible approach to making this possible?

See my example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoVvML).

### CSS

```
.checkbox-on-off {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.checkbox-on-off input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}


.checkbox-on-off input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.checkbox-on-off label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  height: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #b8b8b8;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.checkbox-on-off input[type=checkbox]:checked+label .checked {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  background: no-repeat url('img/www-hitchhiker-vflAhaHWR.png') -421px -78px;
  background-size: auto;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.checkbox-on-off label .checked {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-on-off input[type=checkbox]:checked+label .unchecked {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-on-off label .unchecked {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 3px;
}

.checkbox-on-off input[type=checkbox]:checked+label .toggle {
  float: right;
}

.checkbox-on-off label .toggle {
  float: left;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  height: 15px;
  width: 13px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<span class="checkbox-on-off ">
    <input id="autoplay-checkbox" class="" type="checkbox" checked="">
    <label for="autoplay-checkbox" id="autoplay-checkbox-label">
        <span class="checked">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="unchecked"></span>
        <span class="toggle">&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
</span>

<span class="checkbox-on-off ">
    <input id="autoplay-checkbox" class="" type="checkbox" checked="">
    <label for="autoplay-checkbox" id="autoplay-checkbox-label">
        <span class="checked">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="unchecked"></span>
        <span class="toggle">&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
</span>

<span class="checkbox-on-off ">
    <input id="autoplay-checkbox" class="" type="checkbox" checked="">
    <label for="autoplay-checkbox" id="autoplay-checkbox-label">
        <span class="checked">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="unchecked"></span>
        <span class="toggle">&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
</span>
<span class="checkbox-on-off ">
    <input id="autoplay-checkbox" class="" type="checkbox" checked="">
    <label for="autoplay-checkbox" id="autoplay-checkbox-label">
        <span class="checked">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="unchecked"></span>
        <span class="toggle">&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
</span>
<span class="checkbox-on-off ">
    <input id="autoplay-checkbox" class="" type="checkbox" checked="">
    <label for="autoplay-checkbox" id="autoplay-checkbox-label">
        <span class="checked">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="unchecked"></span>
        <span class="toggle">&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
</span>
<span class="checkbox-on-off ">
    <input id="autoplay-checkbox" class="" type="checkbox" checked="">
    <label for="autoplay-checkbox" id="autoplay-checkbox-label">
        <span class="checked">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="unchecked"></span>
        <span class="toggle">&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
</span>
```

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: @j08691 Understood. You think I need to find another route to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the way around it is to have the inputs **inside** of the `label` element:

```
<label>
 <input type="checkbox">
 Some Checkbox 1
</label>

<label>
 <input type="checkbox">
 Some Checkbox 2
</label>
```

So clicking anywhere inside the `label` will now toggle the checkbox that is also nested inside that `label`. Now you don't need for `for=` attribute on the `label`.

Comment: I'm wondering if I should just make the checkbox cover the entire width of the label and say hell with some of the selectors.

Comment: You can't make the checkbox cover the entire width of the label - a checkbox is an element whose size is predetermined based on the operating system or browser  you're using. This is where the label element becomes helpful - an element that can be given a fixed size and, when you click it, toggles the checkbox. Is there something about this approach that doesn't work for you?

Comment: That's incorrect. Look into the `transform: scale()` property on a checkbox.

Comment: Very hacky, but fair enough (even though you still can't accurately specify a `width` with `transform: scale()`. You still didn't answer my question - what about the markup where the checkbox wrapped in a label doesn't work for your case?

Comment: I'm sorry - I wasn't trying to be rude. I am still playing with it! I need to change my CSS classes, let me play around with it to get it working and then I'll accept. I appreciate it!